# I am unable to connect to MySql Workbench Database from Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, database-connection

I have added MySql connector external Jar file to my project.
I am getting this exception while trying to connect to Database from Eclipse. Please help me.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at myPackage.servletLogin.doPost(servletLogin.java:32)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: `mysql-workbench database` ??

Comment: ensure that the jar contain `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` is in tomcat/lib

Comment: I am using mySql workbench CE

Comment: where can I find tomcat/lib?

Comment: post your connection creation  code and make sure your jar is in Java classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Add the jar somewhere such that eclipse can find it and use the driver from the jar to connect to the database. Refer the below screenshot which might be helpful to you. Otherwise you can always add it to your projects classpath.
[Below is the graphical way to do it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUgDp.jpg)